# Can my landlord offer to renew my lease for a higher price than the listed price in the market?

Tags: rent

Can my US landlord offer to renew my lease for a higher price than the listed price in the market?

Comment: Yes, unless there is a local law prohibiting that.  City and state will matter here.

Comment: Unless it's being done for a specifically illegal reason, like discrimination against a protected class, or there are specific (likely state or local) laws or regulations around it, I'd assume by default the landlord can do as they like. "Introductory rates" are not generally illegal (not that I'm a fan, far from it).